# Obter Resolução da Tela C++

Tags: c++

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema e  gostaria de saber se existe alguma função / biblioteca, qualquer coisa, para pegar a resolução da tela, se ela é por exemplo:

```
1280x720, 1920x1080, 1366x768, etc...
```

Existe algum modo de verificar isto em `C++`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No Windows?

Utilize GetSystemMetrics().

```
#include <windows.h>
Int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
Int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
```

No Linux?

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

Display* disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
Screen*  scrn = DefaultScreenOfDisplay(disp);
int height = scrn->height;
int width  = scrn->width;
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado Rodrigo!

Answer (score 9):

A resposta do colega @RodrigoGuiotti está certíssima e deveria ser aceita. :)

Mas, apenas pra complementar: se você tem intenções adicionais (por exemplo, capturar a imagem da tela pra fazer algo sobre ela), talvez seja mais fácil usar alguma outra biblioteca mais completa do que usar diretamente as funções de base do sistema operacional. Nesse caso, a minha sugestão seria o [Qt](http://www.qt.io/), pois com ele é muito fácil fazer esse tipo de checagem e manipulação com o mesmo código em diferentes plataformas.

A seguir tem um exemplo bem simples que eu preparei, que identifica as resoluções de todas as telas (se vc tiver mais de um monitor, por exemplo - como é o meu caso) e também demonstra como obter uma imagem da tela desejada.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QLabel>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication oApp(argc, argv);

    // Pega a lista de telas disponíveis
    QList<QScreen *> lScreens = QApplication::screens();

    // Gera o relatório de resoluções com todas as telas
    QRect oRes;
    QString sScreen;
    QString sReport = QString("Relatório de resoluções das %1 tela(s):\n\n").arg(lScreens.size());
    foreach(QScreen *pScreen, lScreens)
    {
        oRes = pScreen->availableGeometry();
        sScreen = QString("    Tela %1: %2 x %3\n").arg(pScreen->name()).arg(oRes.width()).arg(oRes.height());
        sReport += sScreen;
    }

    // Exibe as informações da resolução da tela
    QMessageBox::information(NULL, "Resolução", sReport, QMessageBox::Ok);

    // Captura a imagem da tela principal
    QPixmap oScreenImage = QApplication::primaryScreen()->grabWindow(0);

    // Exibe a imagem em uma janela
    QLabel oImage;
    oImage.setWindowTitle("Captura da imagem da tela principal");
    oImage.setPixmap(oScreenImage.scaled(QSize(800, 600), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation));
    oImage.show();

    return oApp.exec();
}
```

O resultado da execução desse código é primeiramente um diálogo como o a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E então uma janela com a imagem capturada do seu monitor principal, como a seguir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Observe que eu executei no Windows, mas vai funcionar da mesma forma
>   no Linux, no Mac, ...

Comment: +1 só porque o QT é cross-platform e suporta diferentes compiladores também :D - ótimo exemplo!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Nós, amantes do Qt, estamos em todo lugar! :) rs

Comment: Obrigado a todos.